# how can I store optimized parameters corresponding to local maximum of a function out of the multiple loops?

Tags: python, for-loop, optimization, scipy, scipy-optimize

I have a 3D array and I want to find the optimal parameters corresponding to a local maximum of 2D array for each iteration of 3rd array as an outer loop there.

```
Nstep1 = 5
l2= linspace(0.01,2,Nstep1)
EP_opt = zeros(Nstep1)
Nstep = 5
for l in range(Nstep1):
    Vp = zeros((Nstep, Nstep))
    g1 = linspace(0.1, 0.5, Nstep)
    g2 = linspace(0.1, 0.5, Nstep)  
    for j in range(Nstep):
        for k in range(Nstep):
            def Ep(pr):
                a,b,c=pr
                return -(a*l2[l]+b*g1[j]*g1[j]-c*g2[k])
            x0=[0,1,1]
            bnds= ((0, 1),(0, 1),(0, 1))
            res=minimize(Ep,x0,bounds=bnds)
            #Vp[j,k,l] = -res.fun# will it help to find local maximum of `Vp` for each `l`.
            Vp[j,k] = -res.fun    
            x1= res.x
   EP_opt[l] = Vp.max()# local maximum for each `l2`
```

how to find the optimized parameters `(x1[0], x1[1], x1[2],g1[j]` and `g2[k]`) corresponding to `Vp.max()` for each `l2`? Thanks.

Comment: Any hint please?

Comment: Your indentation is broken, and we cannot help you unless you provide a reproducible example including EP and "some function"

Comment: @reinderien thanks for spotting indentation, I edited with an example.

Comment: I believe this is a subclass of optimisation called linear programming. I'm going to attempt to write out an example implementation for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your optimisation doesn't make any sense, because - given your objective function - for every index of `l`, the best parameters remain the same. Run this:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize


def Ep(pr: np.ndarray, l: float) -> float:
    a, b, c, g1, g2 = pr
    return -(a*l + b*g1*g1 - c*g2)


def main() -> None:
    Nstep1 = 5
    Nstep = 5
    l2 = np.linspace(0.01, 2, Nstep1)   # 5-vector of coefficients
    g1 = np.linspace(0.1, 0.5, Nstep)   # 5-vector of coefficients
    g2 = g1                             # 5-vector of coefficients

    # for every l,j,k and parameters x1,2,3 there is a value of Ep
    # the optimisation parameters exclude l and include j,k,x1,2,3
    # over those optimisation parameters, there is some maximum Ep.

    initial = np.zeros(5)
    for l, l_val in enumerate(l2):
        res = minimize(
            Ep, x0=initial,
            bounds=(
                (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1),
                (g1[0], g1[-1]),
                (g2[0], g2[-1]),
            ),
            args=(l_val,),
        )
        print(res)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

It will show you that in all five cases of `l`, the best parameter set for x0,1,2,g1,g2 is

`[1. , 1. , 0. , 0.5, 0.1]`

Comment: @ reinderien Thanks. My mistake, as my actual function is complex(with multiple maxima). I just put a random one including parameters. I didn't check it as my focus was on the extraction of optimal parameters for each iteration of l. I will try to edit the function.